# Need to pass values to a range slider Jquery function at run time

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery function about a `range slider`. It's just working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {         

        jQuery("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,            
            min: 55, 
            max: 50000,
            values: [55, 50000],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery("#minValue").val(ui.values[0]);
                jQuery("#maxValue").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        jQuery("#minValue").val(jQuery("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        jQuery("#maxValue").val(jQuery("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
</script>
```

Now, I need to pass the values of `max` and `min` within the function dynamically at run time from MySql database that indicate the range of the slider.

I have tried to set those values by using hidden fields something like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {         

     var mini=document.getElementById("hid_min_price").value;
     var maxi=document.getElementById("hid_max_price").value; 

        jQuery("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,            
            min: mini, 
            max: maxi,
            values: [mini, maxi],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery("#minValue").val(ui.values[0]);
                jQuery("#maxValue").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        jQuery("#minValue").val(jQuery("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        jQuery("#maxValue").val(jQuery("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
</script>
```

but it isn't working. How can then I set the values of `max` and `min` dynamically at run time?

Comment: Does something like `min: <?php echo $row['min'];?>,` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch min max values from database and then assign them to javascript variables inside of the  tag.

Let's assume you're using php, the code would look something like that:

...

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {         

        var mini='.$min.';
        var maxi='.$max.';

        jQuery("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,            
            min: mini, 
            max: maxi,
            values: [mini, maxi],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                jQuery("#minValue").val(ui.values[0]);
                jQuery("#maxValue").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        jQuery("#minValue").val(jQuery("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        jQuery("#maxValue").val(jQuery("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
</script>';
```

...

Where $min and $max contian data from DB.

Comment: I have tried exactly as you say but unfortunately it is still not working. I have even tried `<?php echo $min; ?>` and `<?php echo $max; ?>` but to no avail though.

Comment: I have checked that the values of `var mini` and `var maxi` are set correctly but they aren't available to these statements `min: mini` and `max: maxi`. I don't understand the reason why does it happen.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was overlooking my script. Thank a lot.